# Python openpyxl not writing to cell

Tags: python, python-3.x, openpyxl

I am trying to read a value from an excel say A1 == 4 and using these

```
wb = load_workbook("GameExcel.xlsx")
names = wb.sheetnames
sheet = wb['GameEnviroment']
sheet['C4'].value
```

and it reads the information of the current cell just fine, but it doesn't want to write to the cell. There are no errors, it just doesn't work. this is the write code

```
C3Val = sheet['C4'].value
sheet.cell(row=3, column=4).value = (C3Val + ' 3')
```

Comment: are you using `wb.save('my.xlsx')` after that ?

Comment: no... didn't know that existed. There are no fully fledged scripts I can find online that do this

Comment: quick question, is there a way to run this with the excel open?

Comment: i can with LibreOffice, by using a reloading function, not sure how Excel will handle this (give it a try ?)

Comment: PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'GameExcel.xlsx'. wonder if there is a work around, should this be a private chat? an idea is to have two identical spreadsheets where one updates and opens and the other one closes and updates

Comment: nvm I am opening a new thread

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As said by PRMoureu in the comments above, I needed to run `wb.save('my.xlsx')` after I made my changes to the file